# How do I sum a column based on separate category types, and preserve the zeros?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-apply

Here is my dataframe:

| Id | Category | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 3 |
| 1 | B | 4 |
| 2 | A | 2 |
| 2 | B | 6 |
| 3 | A | 3 |

And here is the output I want:

| Id | Total Hours | A_Hours | B_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 0 |

How do I achieve this?

I tried various methods of grouping and aggregation, even calculating the A_hours series separately and appending it to the dataframe but I didn't find a way to both calculate the zeros  ( based on absence of hours under a particular category) and maintain the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='Category', values='Hours',
                      aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0,
                      margins=True, margins_name='Total')
         .add_suffix('_Hours')
         .drop('Total').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
   Id  A_Hours  B_Hours  Total_Hours
0   1        4        4            8
1   2        2        6            8
2   3        3        0            3
```

Comment: I do have a quick follow up question. I used 'Id' as a stand in for a bunch of columns. One of them is 'Date'. And we only want to consider entries after a certain date. So, you have a situation where someone with id 1 has 10 hours, but all of them were before that target date. So, you would want to show that for Id_1, the count is 0. How do I add this filter to the pivot table?

Comment: @hailthedawn I'd suggest to open a follow-up question with all the details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77441153/how-do-i-add-a-filter-to-a-pivot-table-grouping - made one here

Answer (score 1):

Perform a groupby by both Id and Category to get the hours per category and then pivot.

`df.groupby(['Id', 'Category'])[['Hours']].sum().reset_index().pivot(index = 'Id', columns = 'Category', values = 'Hours').fillna(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer given by @Michael Cao, you can perfom the [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to create the "Total Hours" per row:

```
summary = df.groupby(['Id', 'Category'])[['Hours']].sum().reset_index().pivot(index = 'Id', columns = 'Category', values = 'Hours').fillna(0)
summary.loc[:,'Total Hours'] = summary.sum(axis=1)
```