# How do I add a filter to a pivot table grouping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Follow up to: [How do I sum a column based on separate category types, and preserve the zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77396575/how-do-i-sum-a-column-based-on-separate-category-types-and-preserve-the-zeros/77396876#77396876)

I used 'Id' as a stand in for a bunch of columns. One of them is 'Date'. Here is my dataframe after applying the pivot table method.

| Id | Date | A_Hours | B_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/2/2022 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 2/4/2023 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 6/2/2023 | 3 | 0 |

But because 'Date' was one of the columns I added to the index with 'Id', here is the dataframe for a user with multiple hours entered for multiple dates.

| Id | Date | A_Hours | B_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/2/2022 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 2/3/2023 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2/4/2023 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 6/2/2023 | 3 | 0 |

How do I get the following dataframe:

| Id | 2/3/2023_A_Hours | 2/4/2023_B_Hours | 6/2/2023_A_Hours | 6/2/2023_B_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |

Note that there is an additional filter placed on top of this - Id 1 has all 0s because in our result dataframe, not only are we combining rows into multiple columns for a single id, we only want to calculate hours entered in 2023. (and exclude all dates < 1/1/2023 in the count)

Also note that this time, I don't want to create a new column name '2/4/2023_B_Hours'. I would actually prefer a multi-level index with "A_hours" and "B_hours" under "2/4/2023". The table in StackOverflow doesn't allow me to format it like that.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example input and the matching expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide a reproducible example for clarity.

Assuming this one, we want to consider dates after `2023-01-15` (which are absent in Id 3):

```
   Id        Date Category  Hours
0   1  2023-01-01        A      1   # this should be filtered out
1   1  2023-02-01        A      3
2   1  2023-02-01        B      4
3   2  2023-03-01        A      2
4   2  2023-03-01        B      6
5   3  2023-01-01        A      3   # this should be filtered out
```

You can pre-filter the rows (for example using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)), then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) after pivoting to add the missing Ids:

```
out = (df.query('Date > "2023-01-15"')
         .pivot_table(index='Id', columns='Category', values='Hours',
                      aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0,
                      margins=True, margins_name='Total')
         .add_suffix('_Hours')
         .drop('Total')
         .reindex(df['Id'].unique(), fill_value=0)
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
   Id  A_Hours  B_Hours  Total_Hours
0   1        3        4            7
1   2        2        6            8
2   3        0        0            0
```

Comment: I just added the specific example - but this looks very close to what I wanted! Thank you very much! I added a note to the original question - what do I do if I want a multi-level index?

Comment: Hey, also, I don't really have a single column 'Id' - it's a collection of various attributes to identify uniqueness. So df['Id'].unique() doesn't work when I write out the list of columns, because df['a', 'b', 'c'] is a dataframe, and it says dataframes don't have the method .unique(). How do I reindex in this case?

Comment: Then `df[your_cols].drop_duplicates().merge(output_of_pivot_table).fillna(0)`

Comment: I tried this, but this just drops all entries before 1/1/2023. I don't get the id=3 row from your example output

Comment: sorry use  `how='left'` in the `merge` ;)

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thank you so much! And when I edited my original question to include  an example, I actually asked for a "column grouping" of the Hours by day as well. Could you answer thar as well? I tried to use another pivot table, but it's not really working.